# posix regulation does not work with postgreSQL in trigger function

Tags: regex, postgresql, triggers, posix

I am working on a trigger function, and I only want to insert the data when it satisfies specific format. So I tried to use posix regulation expressions. But none of it seems working.

```
            if(new.tin ~ '\d{10}') then
                if not exists(
                    select *
                    from taxcodes
                    where code = substr(new.tin, 1, 4)
                ) then return null;
                end if;
            end if;
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. If you want to ensure a certain format for a column value, then why not use a check constraint? The select seems to indicate you are trying to implement something like a foreign key on the part of a column value. That in turn indicates a bad database design as it is a sign for a column that isn't atomic. If it was, you could define  a proper foreign key.

Comment: Note that  `'\d{10}'` checks if there are _at least_ 10 digits in the value (e.g. `'ab1234567890xy'` would match). If you want to ensure the value consist of **exactly** 10 digits, you need to anchor the regex left and right `'^\d{10}$'`

Comment: Thank you@a-horse-with-no-name so much for the advice, when change to  '^\d{10}$', things becomes clear.

Comment: You might want to consider using a check constraint and a foreign key nonetheless. Much more efficient then a trigger